# Error using dump file on GCP's Database Migration Service for MySQL: No database selected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database-migration, google-cloud-sql

I'm receiving the following error during the migration process using GCP Database Migration Service for MySQL now using dump file:

> Error importing data: generic::unknown: exit status 1 ERROR 1046
> (3D000) at line 22: No database selected

Any clue?

Comment: Hey, What is the method you are using to migrate the db? Are you using the console or the CLI? If you are using the CLI, what is the exact command you are using? In addition, I think you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation about how to ask a good question here in Stackoverflow

Comment: It was my mistake! I created the dump file incorrectly! Sorry!!! And thanks for the tips!